# Delphi: Create and use socket outside main thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, sockets

Code below is intended to read data via socket within the thread.

```
//main method from dll
function GetSocketData(const IP, Port: PChar): PChar; export; cdecl;
var
  Thread: TMyThread;
  DataIsRead: TEvent;
begin
  DataIsRead := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
  Thread:= TMyThread.Create(DataIsRead, IP, Port);
  DataIsRead.WaitFor(INFINITE);
  Result := BlockAlloc(Thread.ResultData);
  DataIsRead.Free;
  Thread.Free;
end;

TMyThreadBase = class(TThread)
protected
  FResultData: string;
public
  constructor Create;

  property ResultData: string read FResultData;
end;

constructor TMyThreadBase.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False); // Suspended
  FResultData := '';
  FreeOnTerminate := False;
end;

TMyThread = class(TMyThreadBase)
private
  FMyData: TMyData;
  FSocketCom: TSocketCom;
  //other params
protected
  procedure Connect(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Execute; override;
public
  constructor Create(DataIsRead: TEvent; const IP, Port: PChar);
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(const IP, Port: PChar);
begin
  inherited Create;
  /init params/

  CoInitialize(nil);
  FSocketCom := ComCreate(FPort, FIP);
  FSocketCom.OnConnect := Connect;//Connect method sends the special command to the port {`ClientSckt.Socket.SendBuf(B[0], Count)`}
  FSocketCom.Reopen;

  FMyData := TMyData.Create(DataIsRead, FSocketCom);//class used for received data interpretation
  //DataIsRead event is being set when all data is interpreted
  FSocketCom.SetRxFunc(FMyData.NCData);//set method for data interpretation
  FMyData.InitData(...);//init values needed while data is being interpreted
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  CoUninitialize;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  while not Terminated do
    Sleep(100);
  //that is the place where I do not know what to do to wait while OnRead event is fired.
end;

TSocketCom = class(TCustomCom)
private
  ClientSckt: TClientSocket;

  procedure SocketConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  procedure SocketRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
protected
  procedure SetThread; override;
public
  constructor Create;
  destructor  Destroy; override;
  function Open:Boolean;  override;
  function Read( Buf:PAnsiChar; Size:Integer; Wait:Integer = 0 ):Integer;  override;
end;

procedure TCustomCom.SetRxFunc(OnRxData: TRxDataEvent);
begin
  ...
    SetThread;
  ...
end;

function TSocketCom.Open:boolean;
var
  i,j:integer;
begin
  ...
  ClientSckt:=TClientSocket.Create(nil);
  ClientSckt.ClientType:=ctBlocking;
  ClientSckt.HostAndAddress:='127.0.0.0';
  ClientSckt.Port:=1234;
  ClientSckt.OnConnect:=SocketConnect;
  ClientSckt.Open;
  ...
end;

function TSocketCom.Read(Buf:PAnsiChar;Size:Integer; Wait:Integer):Integer;
begin
  if Opened then
    Result:=ClientSckt.Socket.ReceiveBuf(Buf^,Size);
  if Result<0 then Result:=0;
end;

procedure TSocketCom.SetThread;
begin
  inherited;
  ClientSckt.OnRead:=SocketRead;
end;
```

Problem: OnRead event is not fired, though it seams all needed instances are created within the thread. Connection is made and command is sent.

Comment: If you want to wait for the thread you should use `Terminate` to mark it as done and simply call `WaitFor` rather than that `while` loop.

Comment: OK. That will fix problem with holding main thread. But how can I force a socket to be read within this thread? As I saw, only methods call from execute are run withing thread. But socket reading happens when its Read method is called. I can't call it in Execute.

Comment: Why can't you call it in Execute?

Comment: Because it's being called on OnRead event of ClientSocket when server sends the data.

Comment: Load up your onRead event dynamically - see my other post.  If you want to use TClientSocket in thread effectively, it's better to try to avoid plonking components on forms and relying on messages to fire events - just construct a TClientSocket socket in code in the thread constructor or at the top of the 'Execute' method.

Comment: Note that you can use your existing TForm.onRead event, if you want.  You just have to bear in mind that the onRead call will be made by your 'TMyThreadForReading' thread, (ie. no VCL in there - just load your PChar buffer).

Comment: ..and all the usual PChar provisos apply - the PChar buffer must be pre-allocated and long enough to contain all rx data.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of code is a misuse of a thread (and misuse of the `FreeOnTerminate` property), since the calling code is blocked waiting for the thread to terminate, so there is no reason to have a thread in the first place.

With that said, by default `TClientSocket` operates in non-blocking mode, which uses window messages internally to trigger socket events.  The thread that activates the socket needs to have a message loop so thosse socket notifications can be received and dispatched correctly.  Otherwise, you have to use the socket in blocking mode instead, as Martin said.

**Update:**

The updated code you have shown is just plain wrong on multiple levels. The threading is all wrong.  The `TClientSocket` usage is all wrong.  Given the blocking nature of your `GetSocketData()` function, there is no need to use any threads internally at all (especially since you stated that `GetSocketData()` is itself being called in a thread, so the extra threading is overkill), and you should not be bothering with the `TClientSocket` events at all, especially the `OnRead` event in particular as it does NOT get called in blocking mode at all (which is the root of your problem!).

You made your code MUCH more complicated then it needs to be.  Use something more like this instead:

```
function GetSocketData(const IP, Port: PChar): PChar; export; cdecl; 
var 
  ClientSckt: TClientSocket; 
  //other params 
begin 
  Result := nil;
  try
    /init params/ 

    CoInitialize(nil); 
    try
      ClientSckt := TClientSocket.Create(nil); 
      try
        ClientSckt.ClientType := ctBlocking; 
        ClientSckt.HostAndAddress := IP; 
        ClientSckt.Port := Port; 
        ClientSckt.Open; 
        try
          // send the special command to the port from here
          // read all data and interpret from here
          Result := BlockAlloc(...); 
        finally
          ClientSckt.Close;
        end;
      finally
        ClientSckt.Free;
      end;
    finally
      CoUninitialize; 
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I agree 99% - there may be some need for this 'complete encapsulation of the data reception', maybe something to do with a DLL call that returns data from the server with minimum 'support', or perhaps later the DLL may be called from other threads with no message loop, (as you point out, this will not work in non-blocking mode).

Comment: Hmm. Calling code is blocked, but assuming this application has an UI, wouldn't using it this way allow the UI to update while the request is in progress, whereas without the thread that would not happen? I hate it when applications freeze for the duration of a web lookup.

Comment: @eis - the OP suggests that he/she is calling it from the main thread and wishes to wait until the thread has retrieved the data.  This would block the main thread and prevent message-handling until thread signals its completion.  Remy is probably correct in that what the OP is asking for is not what he/she wants.  Certainly, I've posted a gazillion times for decades that waiting in a UI thread event-handler for results from another thread is a really bad idea, but many developers still insist in 'calling threads and waiting for the return'.

Comment: If the blocked function is called within the context of the main thread, then it has to pump the main message queue to keep the UI responsive (`TThread.WaitFor()` does that internally). If you get rid of the thread and use the socket in non-blocking mode directly inside the blocked function, the function still has to pump messages anyway (and manually this time), but those messages will include socket notifications.

Comment: Thank you. Was just checking that there isn't something I'm not getting here.

Comment: In my test application I do a separate thread for each GetSocketData  call. Thus, no window freezing. I wrote as Martin had written below, but I still have a problem - no response. I have a class TSocketCom with TClientSocket instance; its OnRead and OnConnect events reassigned with appropriate TSocketCom methods. Within GetSocketData I do Thread.WaitFor and just wait but OnRead event is not fired. Though OnConnect is. So what should I write in Execute to wait while OnRead event is being fired?

Comment: Maybe I should also add that everything works perfect in main thread when i do `while not DataReading.Done do application.processmessages`. But in this case process load rises up to 25% and I use forms unit in non-visual dll.

Comment: As I said, `TClientSocket` operates in non-blocking mode by default. In that mode, `TClientSocket` creates a hidden window to receive socket notifications with. That window is tied to the thread context that connects the `TClientSocket` instance to the server. As such, that thread context must have an active message loop. Using worker threads does not make any sense in this model.  Use `TClientSocket` in blocking mode instead. Are you doing that yet? Please update your question to show the rest of your socket and threading code that you have not shown yet.

Comment: If you call `TThread.WaitFor()` in the context of a worker thread, it will not pump the calling thread's message queue.  It only does that when called in the context of the main thread.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - TeamB, I have revised code and updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the client<> server communication to occur within this function and the thread MyThreadForReading methods, the easiest way is to construct an instance of TClientSocket in the thread constructor, (or at the top of the Execute method). Pass the PChar, hostAddr, port etc. as constructor parameters.  In the constructor/execute, load up the TClientSocket with the parameters, an onRead event and set the clientType to 'ctBlocking'.  In Execute, connect up and read your data into the PChar in a loop until it's all in.  When it's in, you have some choices to notify your main thread that the PChar buffer is 'full'.  I would PostMessage() something to fire a main-thread message-handler, but if you need your main thread to wait, then use WaitFor() as suggested by David.

Comment: PS - don't forget to close and free the TClientSocket before exiting your thread.